identify a 90s cartoon about characters falling through vertical stripes to a lower dimension
Okay, back between 1993 and 1997 (could be '95) I watched a part of a cartoon and I was amazed by it, I want to find it again. 
It wasn't the commercial hit like Simpsons because I remember my neighbor told me "yeah, this is not that interesting, Simpsons is more interesting". 
I remember this episode where the characters (probably 2) fell through some crack in their own world which was somehow above the normal world, and they started falling through some kind of stripes, consisting of several colors (most probably yellow and red like here, but vertical). 
They fell down to what could be a lower dimension and then they would try to get back up. Eventually, by the end of the episode they were able to go back up in their own world. 
I was trying to figure out if it could be the Jetsons, since they had this "living in the sky" theme, but the characters of this cartoon were looking a bit more yellowish.

Do you perhaps remember what happened in that other dimension? And could you describe these 2 characters in a bit more detail?

hello, i didn't want to add much more because my memory might not be correct. But, as far as i remember, the characters were living a normal life on their earth, but they fell through a crack and started falling down, the background was stripes in different colors. Then, I think they stopped at emptyness or some kind of repeating plane. then, they were able to go up to their earth. By the way, i think the show was named like "Simpsons", "Jetsons", "Flintstones".
@Paulie_D - can you tell me how i could be more descriptive on the question title? can you give me some suggestions? thank you

Maybe it is Mr. Rossi.
The film if from 1960 - 1976. When Mr. Rossi whistle a magic whistle he changed time/universe together with a dog.
You can check some scenes on youtube: 



hello, thank you, but that is not it for sure

Jamie and the Magic Torch? Has a striped helter skelter into a lower world.




hello, i don't recognize this cartoon. it seems older than the 90s cartoons. on the cartoon i was mentioning, i think it was one episode that happened, it wasn't a recurring theme in the show...
